# Have a issue with test class for lead conversion trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test, lead-conversion

I have a trigger on lead conversion with the help of my friend. please find

> Test class failed every time. with error: System.DmlException:
>   ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadConvert: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 1; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required
>   fields are missing: [LastName]: [LastName] Trigger.LeadConvert: line
>   17, column 1: []

below code:

```
trigger LeadConvert on Lead (after update) { 
map<Id, Lead> mapNewLead = trigger.newMap; 
List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>(); 
for(Lead objLead: mapNewLead.values()) 
{ 
    if (objLead.isConverted == true ) 
    { 
        lstContact.add(new contact(LastName = objLead.First_Other_Contact_Name__c,Phone = objLead.First_Other_Contact_Phone__c, 
        Email = objLead.First_Other_Contact_Email__c,AccountId = objLead.convertedAccountId));
        lstContact.add(new contact(LastName = objLead.Second_Other_Contact_Name__c,Phone = objLead.Second_Other_Contact_Phone__c, 
        Email = objLead.Second_Other_Contact_Email__c,AccountId = objLead.convertedAccountId));
        lstContact.add(new contact(LastName = objLead.Third_Other_Contact_Name__c,Phone = objLead.Third_Other_Contact_Phone__c, 
        Email = objLead.Third_Other_Contact_Email__c,AccountId = objLead.convertedAccountId));

    } 
insert lstContact; 
}
}
```

Then I wrote a test class but I am not able to figure put why this test class is fail.

```
@isTest
public class TestLeadConvert{
static testMethod void convertLead(){
    test.startTest();
    Lead lead = new Lead();
    lead.FirstName='Trigger1';
    lead.LastName='Test1';
    lead.Company='Trigger Test1';
    lead.LeadSource='Sales2.0';
    lead.First_Other_Contact_Name__c='Rohit';
    lead.First_Other_Contact_Phone__c='001234';
    lead.First_Other_Contact_Email__c='rsingh@da-desk.com';

    insert lead;

    System.debug('Created and inserted lead');
    //leadconvt.strAccountId= 'lead';
    //leadconvt.strContactId= 'lead';
    //leadconvt.convertlead();
     Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
 lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);

 LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
 lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
 Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);

 // Make sure conversion was successful
 System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

 test.stopTest();

 }   
 }
```

Please help to figure out the issue.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Test class failed every time. with error: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadConvert: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [LastName]: [LastName]

Trigger.LeadConvert: line 17, column 1: []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating data that is wrong as per your trigger code.

You need to mentioned all the fields which used in your trigger.

I suggest add a check if this is null then don't create contact. Or change your test class code..

It should be like this.

```
Lead lead = new Lead();
    lead.FirstName='Trigger1';
    lead.LastName='Test1';
    lead.Company='Trigger Test1';
    lead.LeadSource='Sales2.0';
    lead.First_Other_Contact_Name__c='Russell';
    lead.First_Other_Contact_Phone__c='001234';
    lead.First_Other_Contact_Email__c='r@na.com';
    lead.Second_Other_Contact_Name__c='Russell';
    lead.Second_Other_Contact_Phone__c='001234';
    lead.Second_Other_Contact_Email__c='r@na.com';
    lead.Third_Other_Contact_Name__c='Russell';
    lead.Third_Other_Contact_Phone__c='001234';
    lead.Third_Other_Contact_Email__c='r@na.com';

    insert lead;
```

Comment: Okay..Let me try

Comment: @Russelbaker1 Yes I knew that I should work.